# Dynamic JS channel menu link issue

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat

I'm working on a chat application where users can create channels and chat in them.

Each time a channel link on the side is clicked (channel links are updated each time a new channel is added), I want to update the localStorage 'channel' variable (currentChannel) to the id of the clicked link and load that channels messages on the right side chat window with a socket.on call to the server. However, nothing happens when I click the links.

I might add that all my code is in a document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { }). And although the li-tagged links generated after socket.on('update channels') appear properly on the loaded page, they don't appear in the source HTML for some reason. Any help much appreciated in advance!

Full source: https://github.com/kylepw/project2/blob/master/static/index.js

Code from line 85 that updates the channel links at initialization and when new channels are added.

```
// Update channel list
socket.on('update channels', channels => {
  if (channels) {
    channelsList = channels;
    channelsBar.innerHTML = ``;
    for (let channel of channelsList) {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `<a href="#" class="selectChannel" id="${channel}">${channel}</a>`;

      channelsBar.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
});
```

This (from line 155) is where I'm trying to react to a link click:

```
const selectChannel = document.getElementsByClassName('selectChannel');
//...
// Load clicked channel 
for (let i = 0; i < selectChannel.length; i++) {
  selectChannel[i].addEventListener('onclick', () => {
    currentChannel = this.id;
    localStorage.setItem('channel', currentChannel);
    socket.on('messages', currentChannel); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `this.id` is giving you the expected result. If you inspect the HTML on the page and the id of the channels is correct there, then try modifying your `onClick` function to accept an `e` parameter and get the id from that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectChannel.length; i++) {
     selectChannel[i].addEventListener('onclick', (e) => {
         let currentChannel= e.target.id; //id of the element you clicked
         localStorage.setItem('channel', currentChannel);
         socket.on('messages', currentChannel); 
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Josh. Unfortunately, that didn't work. Another note:
Perhaps because I'm updating the channels in #channelsBar dynamically with socket.on('update channels'), although the links are displayed on the page, the HTML page source doesn't show them there.

Comment: In your `socket.on('update channels')`, you loop over the channels and set  `id="${channel}"`. Are you saying when you view the HTML source, you don't see the correct channel id populated in each `<a>`'s `id` field?